# JavaScript function as parameter error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. Right now I am learning about functions. I don't kow why the following code generates an error.

```
var myFunc= function()
{
return 5;
};

otherFunc(myFunc){
alert(myFunc);
};

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I wrote these 2 functions in Google Chrome's console.

Comment: The second function is not a function, what did you expect ?

Comment: for the second "function" to be a function, it needs to have the word _function_ written before it. `function otherFunc(myFunc){/*...*/}`

Comment: Thank you guys. That was simple. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var otherFunc= function(myFunc){
alert(myFunc);
}
```

or

```
function otherfunc(myFunc){
alert(myFunc);
}
```

thats how functions are defined in js

`otherFunc(myFunc)` is how we call a function and you put a `{` after it, so js runtime says unexpected token `{`